# JNI date value conversion issue, getting a different long value in C++

Tags: c++, date, java-native-interface

I'm badly stuck in one basic date conversion in jni as the (long) values passed from Java to JNI/C++ are quite different.
My Java date objects are initialized in class as,

```
Date date1=new Date(1220227200L * 1000);

// If I convert into milliseconds such as 
long timeInMillisecond=date1.getTime();
System.out.println (timeInMillisecond )
// it obviously displays 1220227200000
```

In my native function, i'm retrieving as

```
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "date1", "Ljava/util/Date");

// case 1 - value 1
jlong dobject =  (jlong) env->GetObjectField(object ,fid);
cout <<dobject;     //displays 139757766370904

// case 2 - value 2
long dobject2 = (long) env->GetObjectField(object, fid);
cout <<dobject2;  // displays 140031771862616

// case 3 - value 3
long long dobject3 = (long long) env->GetObjectField(object ,fid);
cout <<dobject3; //displays  140456034100824
```

I wonder what would be the best way to get correct value here from Java in C++. I'm using C++ 11. Some one please help me here.

**Update**
Sorry guys, i think I misspelled a few variables, so it wasn't dobject2,3 in GetObjectfield (correcting that)and infact rewriting the code here to make it more clear.

```java
//Data.java
class Data {
  public long sDate;
  public Date schedDate;
  ....
}
```

```java
// Test.java    
// Native function
public native static void sendEvent(Data EventRec);
```

```java
Data Rec= new DataRec();
Rec.sDate= 1400754723399L;
Rec.schedDate = new Date(1220227200L * 1000);
sendEvent(Rec);
```

```cpp
//C++
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_sendEvent  (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject jobj) {
    cls = env->FindClass("Data");
    if (cls !=NULL) {
        jmethodID ctorID = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>","()V");
        if (ctorID != NULL) {
            jfieldID fidLong = env->GetFieldID(cls, "sDate", "J");
            long dObj = (long) env->GetLongField(jobj,fidLong);
            cout << "C++ .. Event Date (LONG): " << dObj <<endl; // This is correct  
            jfieldID fidDate = env->GetFieldID(cls, "schedDate", "Ljava/util/Date");
            // Here is the problem area, that I tried to mimic above...             
            jobject dobject= (env->GetObjectField(jobj,fidDate));
            long dobj = env->GetLongField(dobject,fidDate);
            // OR 
            // long dObj2 = (long) env->GetLongField(jobj,fidDate);
            // ..... 
            cout << "C++ .. Date (DATE)..." << dobj;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: A Java `long` is a 64bit type, but a C/C++ `long` MAY be 64bit or 32bit, it is up to the compiler implementation to decide. To ensure a 64bit type, use `long long`, `__int64`, `int64_t`, etc instead. Either way, you are not retrieving the `long` value from JNI correctly to begin with, which is why you are getting so many different results. Starting with, what is `dobject` pointing at in the first call to `GetObjectField()`? Not what you think it is pointing at. And why are you trying to cast the `Date` object (`jobject`) to a `long` (`jlong`) rather than use JNI to call its `getTime()` method?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how your Java code is calling your C++ code in the first place

Comment: Updated code above, hope it makes more sense @Remy

Comment: By the way, `Date` died as of JSR 310.  Use: `Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1220227200L )`

Comment: @BasilBourque I wish I can discard that but unfortunately can't do that. I'm not a Java developer so I'm really struggling in certain basic things as well

Comment: In your updated code you're using the field id of your `sDate` field of your own object in a Java `Date`. That can't possibly work. Use `getTime()` as in @Botje's (with fixed class argument) or @Remy's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JNI code is not accessing the Java objects correctly.

In your `Java_Test_sendEvent()` implementation, the `jclass` parameter points to the class type that your `public native static void sendEvent(Data EventRec);` is declared in (which you did not show), and the `jobject` parameter points to the `Data Rec` object that your `Java` code is passing in to `sendEvent()`.

Also, in your call to `env->GetFieldID()` for the `Date` field, you are missing a required semicolon at the end of the type signature string.

Try this instead:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_sendEvent  (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject EventRec)
{
    jclass cls_EventRec = env->GetObjectClass(EventRec);

    jfieldID fid_sDate = env->GetFieldID(cls_EventRec, "sDate", "J");
    if (!fid_sDate) {
        // error handling...
        return;
    }

    jfieldID fid_schedDate = env->GetFieldID(cls_EventRec, "schedDate", "Ljava/util/Date;");
    if (!fid_schedDate) {
        // error handling...
        return;
    }

    jlong sDate = env->GetLongField(EventRec, fid_sDate);
    cout << "C++ .. Event Date (LONG): " << sDate << endl;

    jobject schedDate = env->GetObjectField(EventRec, fid_schedDate);
    if (schedDate) {
        jclass cls_schedDate = env->GetObjectClass(schedDate);
        jmethodID mid_getTime = env->GetMethodID(cls_schedDate, "getTime", "()J"); 
        jlong timeInMillisecond = env->CallLongMethod(schedDate, mid_getTime);
        cout << "C++ .. Date (DATE)..." << timeInMillisecond << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: see all of my parameters are coming correctly but the schedDate, if the jclass param is wrong, they shouldn't come right? Anyways I switched my entire function with your code and guess what, now jfieldID fid_schedDate is returning 0 for the line to line copied function of you (just added cout << fid_schedDate ) in the error handling part.

Comment: @Naumann the only way I could see `fid_schedDate` being null is if the `Data.schedDate` field is not a `java.util.Date` but is some other `Date` class. This is why you need to update your question to provide a [mcve]. What you provided so far is neither minimal or reproducible as it is missing important details.

Comment: @Naumann The call to `GetFieldID`is missing the semicolon in `"Ljava/util/Date;" `(as in the code in your question). If you get 0 for all ids of Date fields, it's because of that.

Comment: Great guys, i don't know if i can accept two answers, but only that semicolon was the problem here. Man this is the most sensitive library i ever encountered. lol

Answer (score 2):

You're overlooking something very important:

```cpp
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "date1", "Ljava/util/Date;");
jobject dobject = env->GetObjectField(dobject, fid); // Note: "Get Object Field"
```

This returns a `java.util.Date` object. You need to call `getTime` on it as well:

```cpp
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getTime", "()J"); 
jlong timeInMillisecond = env->CallLongMethod(dobject, mid);
```

Comment: Tested and your mid returns 0 here, I wonder what that getTime mean here?

Comment: @Naumann It is retrieving the ID of the `Date.getTime()` method, the same method that your Java code is calling in `long timeInMillisecond=date1.getTime();`  The reason `GetMethodID()` returns 0 is because the `cls` parameter of `Java_Test_sendEvent()` is the wrong parameter to pass in to `GetMethodID()` for the `Date.getTime()` method.  That `cls` points to your own `Data` class, not to the Java `Date` class

Comment: Great, thanks much so this getTime() is the key here, other than the semicolon at the end of "Ljava/util/Date;"

Comment: I actually copied that from your question :) Fixed.